# Bold Text Output in Loop with \\newpage in printr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to bold the output of names in a loop in my PDF document.  It works when I am simply looping, but fails when I introduce `\\newpage`

Here is some simple, sample code to produce what I'm talking about.

````
```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE}
library(printr)
test_group<-c('Bob','Joan','Francois','Ximinea','Raga','Mohandas')
sample_data<-rnorm(6,mean=4.3123,sd=.123)

for(cur_person in test_group){
  cat("\n")
  cat(paste("**",cur_person,"**",sep=""),'\n\n')
  print(sample_data)
  cat('\n')
}

```
````

Here is the result I get:

> **Bob**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438
>   **Joan**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438
>   **Francois**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438
>   **Ximinea**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438
>   **Raga**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438
>   **Mohandas**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438

However, when I add `\\newpage` so I can start each person on a new PDF page, I get a different output.

````
```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE}
library(printr)
test_group<-c('Bob','Joan','Francois','Ximinea','Raga','Mohandas')
sample_data<-rnorm(6,mean=4.3123,sd=.123)

for(cur_person in test_group){
  cat("\\newpage") ## HERE IS NEW LINE
  cat("\n")
  cat(paste("**",cur_person,"**",sep=""),'\n\n')
  print(sample_data)
  cat('\n')
}

```
````

> **Bob**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438
>
> ...  (this shows next page)
>
> **Joan**
>   [1] 4.229853 4.281234 4.575009 4.265584 4.421579 4.445438

*note: this is an artificially simple example to illustrate the problem.  Please don't get hung up on the data.  In my full code, I'm doing a lot more in each loop.*

You can see the output isn't bold but rather, shows the actual stars.  I've tried adding extra returns, taking returns out.  The only change is the introduction of `\\newpage`.

I can't just add lines to space out the pages, as each loop is variable length, and defeats the whole point of `\\newpage`.

Anyone have any idea what I can do to fix?

tech notes:
- R version 3.2.3
- Knitr version: 1.11
- printr version: 0.0.4
- YAML version: 2.1.13
- Windows 7, x64
- Knitting via RStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in one more hard return (`\n`) in the `for` loop, as below, and it works. I don't know the mechanism though, but it seems like LaTex gets unhappy when there are commands so close to a `\newpage`.

````
```{r results='asis',echo=FALSE}
test_group<-c('Bob','Joan','Francois','Ximinea','Raga','Mohandas')
sample_data<-rnorm(6,mean=4.3123,sd=.123)

for(cur_person in test_group){
  cat("\\newpage")
  cat("\n \n")
  cat(paste("**",cur_person,"**",sep=""),'\n\n')
  print(sample_data)
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

Comment: This worked!  I tried `\n\n` but not `\n \n`  the extra space made **all** the difference.

Comment: For me the ```cat(paste("**",cur_person,"**",sep=""),'\n\n')``` does result in a bold string output of cur_person, but ** before and after. How to have it bold?